# Generate a catalog for print and web

Tags: pdf-generation, catalog

I need to create a solution, which allows a database driven catalog to be generated.

Assume, there are a bunch of products, images, prices, other details, and admin can generate catalogs based on "templates".

These templates essentially are "styles" of pages. For instance, style 1, could have 4x4 layout (16 products, with image and other attributes), hence on each page, upto 16 products and details could be displayed. Style 2 could have 2x2 layout, 4 products, but more detail. Admin can pick and choose different styles in a catalog.

Once the catalog is generated, it needs to be put up for either web viewing (lower fidelity) and/or print publishing (higher fidelity).

I would like help in determining the optimum stack to use, particularly, to "code" template and consequently to generate the PDFs.

Factors to consider

- Minimum coding effort (reuse commercial or foss)
- I will prefer an existing software which can create/edit "template" so I don't have to do that. I can simply get the license and reuse that functionality.

What I have considered so far is the following

1. Adobe XFA Forms as templates, connected to database to generate PDF.

   - I not sure which program can generate XFA templates. Acrobat X is an option however it does not seem to have control for adding images. The LiveCycle Server seems to be an overkill.
2. Use iText library, no idea if templates are possible or not, generate for web/print. Has good support for size/quality of catalog to print.
3. Use Open office, make template, and write the glue to retrieve data and generate an open office doc, which can easily be converted into html/pdf. No idea how tough/easy this is.
4. EDIT: Adobe Framemaker allows templates - I am evaluating if it can do the job that i have in mind. I will post an update once I am done.

I have no experience with any of these technologies, so if you can guide/rate them, or add other options that I did not consider.

At this point I am language agnostic. Alot of libraries provide hooks from various languages, so I don't think that will be a problem. If your solution is specific to foo language, please mention it as well.

Thanks for taking the time.

**There is a followup question I asked on graphicsdesign exchange. https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2318/use-data-merge-of-indesign-using-console-or-through-an-api**

Comment: Have you considered hiring a consultant?

Comment: @Jared Yes, I could do that, but I need to do the relevant research first, and be convinced, it is the best solution. No offence meant, but consultants tend to push their own agendas/strengths/experience. Since, whatever I choose, I have to support it. I doubt this is the first time someone has a need for such a software, so if I can reuse something, all the better.

Comment: You're right, it's not the first time. I had someone approach me about fixing an online setup similar to your description (an online greeting card design system) that someone else had built, that outputted PostScript files on the server. It's not impossible to do something like this; it would just take someone sitting down and hammering out the details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about [Adobe inDesign Data Merge](http://www.adobe.com/designcenter/indesign/articles/indcs2at_datamerge.html). [And video here](http://tv.adobe.com/watch/instant-indesign/automating-a-catalog-with-data-merge/)

Pretty easy to use aswel.

Comment: It looks like I will go with Indesign. I have chosen to use import XML feature using tags. I also posted a followup question on graphicsdesign [http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2318/use-data-merge-of-indesign-using-console-or-through-an-api] since I wanted to make it as much a 1 click process as possible. I will go with using tags importing XML, if the user wants to meddle with the result later, they have the option of doing so, otherwise they can simple generate appropriate (pdf|web) catalog.

Comment: IF you're good with using only 1 data source and 1 template, then indesign is good.
If instead you have to create something different on every page (like image on first page with 3 rows of data, then all data on the second page without images and then maybe a third page with only images, then indesign sux for that. 
I would try the free Scribus with the script ScribusGenerator.

Answer (score 0):

TCPDF (PHP) would give you quite a bit of control, and has lots of example code.

http://www.tcpdf.org/

I've used it before, it's not too hard to figure out.

Comment: Thanks, I also need to be able to author the templates, preferably with a GUI. If I am able to get that off the shelf, I would prefer that.

Comment: @Nasir - A custom web interface for constructing/editing your html, while not necessarily trivial, is not too difficult either, given someone with the right skills and experience. The HTML->PDF process is a bit more difficult, so something like TCPDF would be immensely helpful in developing a workflow. jQuery/MooTools, for instance, would help on the client side. It's just a matter of putting the pieces together and getting it all working.

Comment: I agree that it is build-able, but given the choice between using something like indesign to author the template, some sort of simple program to pick the template and merge with data to produce a PDF, I would rather pick indesign (or something like it). Less code to write, means less bugs to fix. I don't mind having a desktop application, as long as it gets the job done.

Comment: @Nasir - I thought you were building a website. Nevermind then; I would also recommend InDesign, in that case. Sorry for the confusion. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if its a good fit, but maybe http://issuu.com/#whatIsIssuu

Comment: Hmm, I will investigate, but at first glance does not seem to do what I have in mind, particularly the templates. It is a good solution to embed/host an existing PDF for the web though. Also, pricey in the long run, particularly with heavy usage.